# How to query for two where clauses

Tags: socrata, soda

Have trouble getting multiple results. I can achieve what i want with a couple calls to the API endpoint but i wanted to make sure i wasn't missing something.

```
Endpoint: https://data.cms.gov/resource/vzbp-x4iv.json
```

I am using this for multiple codes but one state and it works fine.

```
https://data.cms.gov/resource/vzbp-x4iv.json?$$app_token=XXX&$where=hcpcs%20in(%27CODE1%27,%27CODE2%27)&referring_provider_state=Ohio
```

In SQL I would write it as ...

```
SELECT ...
FROM hcpcs
LEFT JOIN referral_state ...
WHERE hcpcs in ('code1', 'code2') 
AND (referral_state = 'State1'
OR referral_state = 'state2'
OR referral_state = 'state3 ... )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to combine multiple `$where` clauses into a single query, you can just `AND` or `OR` them together like you'd do in SQL:

https://dev.socrata.com/docs/queries/where.html

Is that what you were thinking?

Comment: That was exactly it. Thanks!